# Can't initialize variables inside of when statement in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

For whatever reason, my Kotlin program won't initialize variables assigned inside a when statement. Here's the code:

```
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.random.nextInt

val mood: String

when(Random.nextInt(1..2)) {
    1 -> {
        mood = "loud"
        println("$mood")
    }
    2 -> {
        mood = "quiet"
        println("$mood")
    }
}

println("$mood")
```

The lines inside the when statement are printed, but when I run the last line, I get a "Variable 'mood' must be initialized" error.

I don't know what I could possibly be doing wrong here...

Comment: How are you "running" your program? Is this code enclosed by `fun main() { ... }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kotlin, variables declared with the val keyword must be initialized at the point of declaration or in the constructor of the class. In your code, the mood variable is declared without an initial value, and you are trying to assign values to it inside the when statement. However, the compiler is unable to determine if either of the branches will be executed at runtime, so it doesn't consider the variable as fully initialized.

To fix this issue, you can either declare the mood variable as a var instead of a val or assign an initial value to it when declaring it. Here's an updated version of your code using a var:
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.random.nextInt

```
var mood: String

when (Random.nextInt(1..2)) {
    1 -> {
        mood = "loud"
        println("$mood")
    }
    2 -> {
        mood = "quiet"
        println("$mood")
    }
}

println("$mood")
```

By using a var instead of a val, you indicate that the variable can be reassigned later. Since the mood variable is assigned within both branches of the when statement, the compiler no longer complains about it being uninitialized.

Note that the order of the when branches should cover all possible cases, otherwise you might encounter a "when expression must be exhaustive" warning. In your case, the range of nextInt is 1 to 2, so the two branches should be sufficient.

Comment: You need `lateinit var`.

Comment: Yes, without `lateinit`, the compiler will still complain. It cannot detect that the when statement is exhaustive unless the subject is an enum, Boolean, or sealed type. In all other cases, it is only exhaustive if it has an else branch. Using `lateinit` is your promise to the compiler that you'll make sure its initialized before use. IMO, it would be clearer to add an else branch to the when statement.

Answer (score 3):

This is a compilation error, not an execution one.

Your `when` statement is not exhaustive from the compiler point of view because an `Int` can be more than just 1 or 2. The fact that, in practice, `nextInt(1..2)` only returns those numbers is not taken into account by the compiler, which is looking at the type.

To solve the issue you should add an else statement where you also initialize `mood`, e.g.:

```
val mood: String

when (Random.nextInt(1..2)) {
    1 -> {
        mood = "loud"
        println(mood)
    }

    2 -> {
        mood = "quiet"
        println(mood)
    }
    else -> {
        mood = "currently impossible"
    }
}

println(mood)
```

Alternatively you can use a regular `var` or `lateinit var` instead of a `val`.

Either you initialize a regular var directly:

```
var mood: String = ""
```

Or use a lateinit var:

```
lateinit var mood: String
```

In the latter case, the compiler can't ensure initialization anymore (which is actually why it's complaining in the first place in you code).

Also, both of these might be not desiderable if you want to enforce `mood` to be read-only after initialization.